# Trigger some vbs code on filename change

Tags: vbscript

I would like to be able run some custom vb script code upon filename change (for instance to keep a list of newly created files or the ones which changed their name).
The vbs should be called on every filename change happening within a specified folder.

I know how to do that with a full directory scan but I would like to find a more efficient method, for instance by the mean of a sort of OS hook calling my code.

Any way to do that ?

Thank you,
A.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try [WMI](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%5Bvbs%5D+CIM_DataFile+__InstanceOperationEvent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two simple WMI examples, tracing changes for `*.txt` files in `C:\Test\` folder.

First one is for synchronous event processing:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim oWMIService, oEvents, s

Set oWMIService = GetObject("WinMgmts:\\.\root\CIMv2")
Set oEvents = oWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " & _
    "WITHIN 1 WHERE " & _
    "TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND " & _
    "TargetInstance.Drive = 'C:' AND " & _
    "TargetInstance.Extension = 'txt' AND " & _
    "TargetInstance.Path = '\\Test\\'")
Do
    With oEvents.NextEvent()
        s = "Event: " & .Path_.Class & vbCrLf
        With .TargetInstance
            s = s & "Name: " & .Name & vbCrLf
            s = s & "File Size: " & .FileSize & vbCrLf
            s = s & "Creation Date: " & .CreationDate & vbCrLf
            s = s & "Last Modified: " & .LastModified & vbCrLf
            s = s & "Last Accessed: " & .LastAccessed & vbCrLf
        End With
        If .Path_.Class = "__InstanceModificationEvent" Then
            With .PreviousInstance
                s = s & "Previous" & vbCrLf
                s = s & "File Size: " & .FileSize & vbCrLf
                s = s & "Last Modified: " & .LastModified & vbCrLf
            End With
        End If
    End With
    WScript.Echo s
Loop
```

The second is for asynchronous event processing:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim oWMIService, oSink

Set oWMIService = GetObject("WinMgmts:\\.\root\CIMv2")
Set oSink = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "Sink_")
oWMIService.ExecNotificationQueryAsync oSink, _
    "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " & _
    "WITHIN 1 WHERE " & _
    "TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND " & _
    "TargetInstance.Drive = 'C:' AND " & _
    "TargetInstance.Extension = 'txt' AND " & _
    "TargetInstance.Path = '\\Test\\'"
Do
    WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop

Sub Sink_OnObjectReady(oEvent, oContext)

    Dim s

    With oEvent
        s = "Event: " & .Path_.Class & vbCrLf
        With .TargetInstance
            s = s & "Name: " & .Name & vbCrLf
            s = s & "File Size: " & .FileSize & vbCrLf
            s = s & "Creation Date: " & .CreationDate & vbCrLf
            s = s & "Last Modified: " & .LastModified & vbCrLf
            s = s & "Last Accessed: " & .LastAccessed & vbCrLf
        End With
        If .Path_.Class = "__InstanceModificationEvent" Then
            With .PreviousInstance
                s = s & "Previous" & vbCrLf
                s = s & "File Size: " & .FileSize & vbCrLf
                s = s & "Last Modified: " & .LastModified & vbCrLf
            End With
        End If
    End With
    WScript.Echo s

End Sub
```

More info on `CIM_DataFile` instance properties you can find by [the link on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your script is working fine!